# Silverlight, wpf measure TextBlock text problem!

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight-4.0, textblock

I cannot get proper desired size of my TextBlock.

I have few lines of code:

```
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
        block.Style = this.TextStyle;
        block.UpdateLayout();
        block.Measure(new Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
        block.Text = "3333";

        return block.DesiredSize;
```

And i cannot solve two problems with it:

1. block.DesiredSize.Width is always
   zero. When height calculated
   properly.
2. Desired Size not changes when i set setters for style "TextStyle"
   For example setter set for FontSize with value 50.

   ```
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
               Value="50">
       </Setter>
   ```

   But Desired height only 15! What wrong with this measure method? And how can i get real size of text block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
    block.Text = "3333";
    block.Style = this.TextStyle;

    block.Measure(new Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
    block.UpdateLayout();


    return block.DesiredSize;
```

Comment: Yes, this solves first problem. But how to measure with font size which set in setter?

Comment: To resolve 2nd issue as well, i have changed code a little bit, check again please.

Comment: Nothing... The TextBlock font size = 12 when in setter i have 50. And text measured for 12. :(

Comment: Remove the setter code and put that logic also in your code just before measure and update layout.

Comment: But this setter is set in style TextStyle; And this is requirment to make text block style managable and measure proper size.

Comment: I wish i could help you more in proper way, but unfortunatly SL project type is not istalled on this machine, i will try to give you answer in few hours if no one answered it. you can delete this comment after reading it.